# Why is the row expanding to full container width in flutter?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I am making a widget which will contain message with profile picture and name of sender.
But when I am inserting the row containing the profile picture and sender's name it is using
more than required width.

**MessageWidget**

```
class GroupTextMessage extends StatelessWidget {
  final String _id;
  final String _sender;
  final String _content;
  final String _time;

  const GroupTextMessage(
      {required final String id,
      required final String sender,
      required final String content,
      required final String time})
      : _id = id,
        _sender = sender,
        _content = content,
        _time = time;
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    bool isMe = _sender == FirebaseService.currentUserEmail;
    final displaySize = MediaQuery.of(context).size;
    return Container(
      margin: EdgeInsets.only(
          top: kDefaultPadding / 5.0,
          bottom: kDefaultPadding / 5.0,
          left: isMe ? displaySize.width * .20 : kDefaultPadding / 5.0,
          right: isMe ? kDefaultPadding / 5.0 : displaySize.width * .20),
      child: Column(
        crossAxisAlignment:
            isMe ? CrossAxisAlignment.end : CrossAxisAlignment.start,
        children: [
          Material(
            elevation: 1.0,
            color: isMe ? Color(0xAA2EA043) : Color(0xAA1F6FEB),
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
              topLeft: Radius.circular(kDefualtBorderRadius),
              topRight: Radius.circular(kDefualtBorderRadius),
              bottomRight:
                  isMe ? Radius.zero : Radius.circular(kDefualtBorderRadius),
              bottomLeft:
                  isMe ? Radius.circular(kDefualtBorderRadius) : Radius.zero,
            ),
            child: Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
              child: Column(
                crossAxisAlignment:
                    isMe ? CrossAxisAlignment.end : CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                children: [
                  //Problem causing Row
                  if (!isMe)
                    Row(
                      children: [
                        CircularProfilePicture(
                          email: _sender,
                          radius: displaySize.width * 0.03,
                        ),
                        SizedBox(width: kDefaultPadding / 4.0),
                        TextStreamBuilder(
                          stream: FirebaseService.getStreamToUserData(
                              email: _sender),
                          key: UserDocumentField.DISPLAY_NAME,
                          style: TextStyle(
                            letterSpacing: 1.5,
                            fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                            color: Colors.white,
                          ),
                        )
                      ],
                    ),
                  if (!isMe) SizedBox(height: kDefaultPadding / 4.0),
                  Text(_content,
                      style:
                          TextStyle(color: Colors.white, letterSpacing: 1.5)),
                  SizedBox(height: kDefaultPadding / 5.0),
                  Text(_time,
                      style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black87, fontSize: 10.0)),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

**Without using that Row**

[image]

**When using that Row**

[image]

**What I want**

[image]

I want row to use only required width. But it is occupying the whole container width.

Please help me to resolve this issue.

Comment: how about adding `mainAxisSize=min` at top level column+row

Comment: how about adding `mainAxisSize=min` at top level column+row

Answer (score 0):

In your CircularProfilePicture class, are you using expanded or defining a Container size in there?

That could be what's causing the issue.

Comment: No! @Damian A, whatever the widget inside that row it causing the same issue. But I got the fix in the comments. All we have to do is to set mainAxisSize to MainAxisSize.min in row.